# PHP Script error [Uses CuRL]

Tags: php, curl

I recently ran into an error with my PHP Script just recently while adding it to my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VPS.

On my VPS I do have apache, PHP and CuRL installed, so I am wondering if I possibly missed something in the installation process or something. This Sniper is aimed to "Snipe" (Sniping means like sending loads of requests to a server and attempt to win the Name Change).

While attempting to get the name I wanted for this game I play I ran into this error which caused me to lose: "PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /run/apache/Sniper.php on line 68". I am not sure what caused this. When I ran it on my Windows Laptop running PHPMyAdmin it ran just fine, but on my VPS it doesn't seem to be working. I am wondering if any of you guys can help.

Here is the code: 
http://pastebin.com/5AizGGU7 (Had to put it in a pastebin as it's a fairly long and complex script).

Comment: As-is, this question is likely to be closed for a number of reasons -- it's Too Broad (pick one question - you have at least 3); your code is missing. If it's too long, reduce it to a [mcve] and *include it here* to increase your chances of getting a decent answer.

Comment: Just do `print_r($authToken);` BEFORE line 68 to see what's actually in `$authToken` (And Paul is totally right BTW)

Comment: What is exactly result of that page ? It's html ? Or json? xml ? If HTML then I will suggest to use regext to extract value from field.

Comment: @AlonEitan I've taken the steps and removed the excess questions. Also, when I type "print_r($authToken);" before line 68, I get this error: http://pastebin.com/uVm0gUe1